# How to remove nav-bar after click on login menu item in yii2?

Tags: widget, yii2

[image]

I have to remove nav bar after click on login i.e on login page I want to remove nav-bar...How to do this please help me I am new in yii2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the main reason is do not have the navbar when the user is not logged in you can always wrap the navbar inside an if statement checking if the user is logged in first before show the navbar:

```
if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
   // my navbar
}
```

Now, if you meant specifically for this controller/action, you can accomplish that with checking the controller and the action inside your layout:

```
if (Yii::$app->controller->id !== 'YourController' && Yii::$app->controller->action->id !== 'YourAction') {
   // my navbar
}
```

Or you can specify a layout in your action:

```
public function actionYourAction()
{
    $this->layout = 'layoutName';
}
```

Comment: I can't understand..Can you explain it coz I do not wanna navbar when the  user is not logged i.e after click on login nav item nav-bar disable on login page